# Exacttarget and Microsoft CRM - Custom Unsubscribe/ profile center LP

Tags: marketing-cloud

for one of our customer, we use Exact target and Microsoft Dynamics CRM (onpremise). And currently the action for unsubscribe from Email sets only the BULK EMAIL field of the contact entity of the CRM. WE would like to have custom created Landing pages in Exacttarget for Unsubscribe/subscribe/ profile center and link them to the emails rather than the default one .Also, we would like to have other fields in CRM to be sets rather than just BULK Email field .

Wonder if its doable ? ... ET and CRM communication for unsubscribes-subscribes ....

Any Ideas Guyz?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of items you can use for this.  Easiest would be to take a look at publication list sending from MSCRM.
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/publication_lists/publication_list_mapping/

Alternatively, if you're wanting a true custom profile center, you need to set up the SmartCapture Proxy: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/smart_capture/

and then you can use the MSCRM AMPScript functions to read/write MSCRM data: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_microsoft_dynamics_crm/

The ExactTarget Services team can help with this implementation if needed - ask your ET Rep if you need to contract them!

Hope this helps, Sam